# How to adhere rubber threshold to flooring

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

We have horse stall mats that meet LVT. I have a rubber threshold that requires me to glue it down. What is the least intrusive product should I use to adhere it down to the flooring without make a huge mess? [image]

Comment: Most glues will leave a mess when you try to remove what was glue down.  Would only place glue on the rubber mat side instead of both, if you plan on removing the threshold or mat.  Glue on the LVT will ruin it if you try to remove, be okay if it down for life.

Comment: @crip659 that’s sort of what I am thinking. Just can’t decide if I want to ever remove it. The mats are less expensive and easier to replace than the flooring for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Work neatly, use masking tape on either side (helps with "huge mess" containment) and either "follow the manufacturer's recommendations for type of glue" or (at a guess, if the manufacturer is actually silent on the subject, which would be surprising) use contact cement, which allows you to coat both sides, let them dry, insert some waxed paper while you line them up, and then slide the waxed paper out while pressing the two surfaces together.